# Create a data.frame from multiple textfiles with rownames as columns in r

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, lapply, sapply

A am a Newby in r and I already fail at reading in my files.

I have a list of 1100 .txt-files.
The first 4 rows are the metadata ("Newspaper", "Date", "Ressort", "Title")
The Text begins in the fith row.

**PROBLEM** I don't get the data.frame done. I appears as a loop of my first .txt-file.

**So, this is what I tried**

I read them in r with `list.files()` and write a for-loop

```
datalist <- list.files()

for(i in datalist){
  test <- readLines(i, encoding = 'UTF-8')
}
```

The first file ist the `test`-file

```
test <- readLines(i, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

The `test`-file gives me the metadata

```
meta <- test[1:4]
```

Then I define the 5th row as text and remove the line breaks

```
text <- paste(test[5:length(test)], collapse = '')
```

Then I create my data.frame with the meta as columns and the text

```
df <- data.frame(datalist, Newspaper = meta[1], Date = meta[2], Resssort = meta[3], Text = text)
df
```

Writing as csv - sure

```
write.csv(df, "test.csv")
```

The Problem is now, that my columns are well set, but in every line the same data appears and it is the data from test in the for-loop.
Any Ideas?
Would be so pleased and grateful to get some tipps or answers!
Cheers Y'all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution using `{purrr}`'s `map_dfr` to map a list of file names to a (custom) function to read the data. The main advantages of such a solution is that you don't have to create a list of data frames
to merge them together afterwards and by avoiding the loop you don't have to create temporary objects that would clutter your working environment. All objects created within the function only live within the function.

The disadvantage is that it might be harder in the beginning to understand what goes on behind the scenes, while writing a for loop, every step is more explicit. If you have the time, I encourage you to take a time to [The Joy of Functional Programming (for Data Science)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bzUmK0Y07ck) video from Hadley Wickham. At around 8 minutes onwards he talks about exactly this kind of problem you are facing. But the whole video is worth its time! :)

```
library(tidyverse)
datalist <- list.files("data/newspaper", full.names = T)

custom_read_lines <- function(file) {
  # define function to read files and return a data frame already as expected
  # in final output
  whole_file <- readLines(file)
  text <- paste(whole_file[5:length(whole_file)], collapse = '')

  df <- data.frame(
    Newspaper  = whole_file[1],
    Date       = whole_file[2],
    Ressort    = whole_file[3],
    Title      = whole_file[4],
    Text       = text
  )

  return(df)
}

## using purrr's map_dfr to map each entry of data list to the custom function
df_merged <- datalist %>% map_dfr(custom_read_lines)

df_merged %>% as_tibble() #just for nicer output
# A tibble: 3 x 5
# Newspaper   Date      Ressort Title             text
# <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <chr>             <chr>
# 1 Nice News   2021-01-… ressort Where does it co… "Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of …
# 2 Boring News 2020-11-… ressort Why do we use it? "It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a pa…
# 3 Old News    1990-01-… ressort What is Lorem Ip… "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has bee…



# in case your data looks a bit different and you want to try out first you can always try
# the function for a single file, if it works you can then pass it to the map_dfr function

first_file <- datalist[2]
custom_read_lines(first_file) %>% as_tibble()
# A tibble: 1 x 5
# Newspaper   Date      Ressort Title         text
# <chr>       <chr>     <chr>   <chr>         <chr>
#   1 Boring News 2020-11-… ressort Why do we us… It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page wh…
```

each of the 3 examples files looked more or less like the following:

```
Nice News
2021-01-01
ressort
Where does it come from?
Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text.
It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old.
Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source.
```

Comment: It really worked that way. thank you.  For utf-8 encoding I added ```whole_file <- readLines(file, encoding = 'UTF-8')``` and now we`re good. Again. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I follow, but do you first do this loop:

```
for(i in datalist){
  test <- readLines(i, encoding = 'UTF-8')
}
```

followed by this line:

```
test <- readLines(i, encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

Because if so, you are rewriting `test` and you will only get `datalist[i]` in your test variable. Anything you do afterwards will just resample from this one file that's on `datalist[I]` - and that should basically be the last file of the datalist.

If not, then I'm not sure where it goes wrong, but if you suspect it is the for loop you could alternatively do something like this:

```
temp=paste('/completepathof/mapyourfilesarein',list.files(path='/completepathof/mapyourfilesarein'),sep='')
             
myfiles = lapply(temp, readLines,encoding = 'UTF-8')
```

This should work (I used it with read.csv but don't see why it shouldn't work with readLines).

Also if you want to pinpoint where it goes wrong use the command str(test), or str(df) (so that is str(whatever you are interested in) after you run a line to see whether you changed something unexpectedly and whether columns and data is read / transformed in the correct way. I hope this helps a little bit.

Comment: Thank you a lot. Temp and my files work but I get the error: Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
 arguments imply different number of lines: 10, 6, 8, 14, 7 and I cant write a csv or a data frame

Comment: Where do you get the error? After the lapply function? or when you create the dataframe? Since you are putting a lot of different files (and also the list of files) in 1 data.frame this could result in unequal row numbers, that could lead to a problem. If you look at your files in the following: df <- data.frame(datalist, Newspaper = meta[1], Date = meta[2], Resssort = meta[3], Text = text) : do they have a length of 10, 6, 8, 14 and 7 respectively? (you can check with length(datalist), length(meta[1]) etc.)

Comment: To be honest I am a bit confused as to what you want to do. Do you want a dataset with only the metadata? Or a dataset with only the data?

Comment: A datest with both, the metadata as columns and the data .

Comment: A datest with both, the metadata as columns and the data . With temp and myfiles, I get the meatadata in the rows, but they are still not defined as columns (Newspaper, Date, Ressort, Title, Text). When I try to write the csv after the myfiles, i get: write.csv(myfiles, "files.csv")
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 46, 10, 6, 8, 14, 7

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly, the meta-data are the variables you have in the text and in the text you have columns with data corresponding to these variables? Maybe you should look at the dataset you made : View(df) and see what goes wrong. If you want to give column names to a dataframe you can do the following: colnames(df) <-  c('newspaper','ressort', etc.) you will have to have the right amount of columns in your dataframe to do this. Maybe you should try loading the data as a table (e.g. using read.table or read.delim : see [continue]

Comment: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/reading-data-from-txt-csv-files-r-base-functions 

I think what is going wrong now is that you have an unclear idea of what the structure in your dataset should look like. A data.frame in r should in general have equal rows and equal columns, although there are some workarounds if that is not the case (filling missing rows and columns with NAs). Try to also use the following if you're unsure about functions ?function (e.g. ?read.delim) to see how the function works. Last tip, if I understand correctly, the data starts from the [cont]

Comment: 5th row. What I would suggest you do (if possible, depends on how the data is saved in the txt. file) is using read.table or read.delim or read.delim2 and then in the brackets add: skip=4, which should skip the first 4 lines in the data. You might need to say that the header=0 if there's not header. Another important parameter to set is the separator. If you have the data structured as columns in .txt they are separated by a space, or comma, or something else, you can set this separator in this way in the brackets of the function: sep = ' ' (for space), sep = ',' for comma.

Comment: function should look like: read.table(i, skip=4, header=FALSE, sep=','). Similarly you can load the metadata by: read.table(i, header=FALSE, sep=',', nrows=4) (to only read the first 4 rows). I hope this, together with colnames(df)<-('x','b',etc) will work.

Comment: Thank you. With the answer above and tidyverse it all went well. The problem was that i had to write a function instead of a loop where all the infos (metadata, text, aso) are in. Thank you for your help and your precious time